No refresh token from Google OAuth2
I can't seem to obtain refresh token from oauth2.Exchange() for an app under testing.
config.Exchange(ctx, code, oauth2.AccessTypeOffline, oauth2.ApprovalForce)

returns an access token with no refresh_token. What's even more annoying is that oauth2.ApprovalForce does not prompt an OAuth consent screen for some reason. It only prompts for the very first time, and even after consenting for the first time, does not return a refresh token.
Checking the request through the debugger, the following is sent in the body of the request:
access_type=offline&client_id=...&client_secret=...&grant_type=authorization_code&prompt=consent&redirect_uri=...

So the library should be working fine. I've added a custom option
SetAuthURLParam("approval_prompt", "force")

and that also doesn't seem to work
Edit: Add code snippets
Initiating the OAuth flow:
func TestRegister(ctx context.Context, c *app.RequestContext) {
    var err error
    var req register.RegisterReq

    // ...

    var oauthState string
    if oauthState, err = getOAuthState(c); err != nil {
        c.JSON(400, map[string]any{"Error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    url := config.AuthCodeURL(oauthState)
    c.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, []byte(url))
    return
}

func getOAuthState(c *app.RequestContext) (string, error) {
    expiration := 60 * 60 * 24
    cookieName := "authstate"
    b := make([]byte, 16)
    var err error
    if _, err = rand.Read(b); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    state := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b)
    c.SetCookie(cookieName, state, expiration, "/", "localhost", protocol.CookieSameSiteLaxMode, false, false)
    return state, nil
}

OAuth callback
func TestOauthCallback(ctx context.Context, c *app.RequestContext) {
    var err error
    var req register.OauthCallbackReq

    // ...

    queryArgs := &register.OauthCallbackReq{}
    if err = c.BindQuery(queryArgs); err != nil {
        c.JSON(500, map[string]any{"Error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    var token *oauth2.Token
    if token, err = oauthAuthorize(ctx, queryArgs); err != nil {
        c.JSON(500, map[string]any{"Error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    _ = token

    // ...
}

func oauthAuthorize(ctx context.Context, queryArgs *register.OauthCallbackReq) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    var token *oauth2.Token
    var err error
    if token, err = config.Exchange(ctx, code, oauth2.AccessTypeOffline, oauth2.ApprovalForce); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return token, err
}

Edit 2
It seems that you're supposed to provide the oauth2.AccessTypeOffline and oauth2.ApprovalForce args in AuthCodeURL(), not when requesting for the access token 

did you create a web app or an installed app?

@LindaLawton-DaImTo It's a web app

Do me a favor go into the users google account under connections check for your app if its not there tell me.  if it is remove it then try again and tell me if you get a refresh token.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo Yup I've removed the app multiple times and even when granting permission for the very first time, it does not return a refresh token

You should include a [example] i cant help anymore without seeing the rest of your code.  but try following this https://medium.com/@_RR/google-oauth-2-0-and-golang-4cc299f8c1ed

@LindaLawton-DaImTo I've added some code snippets. The token obtained here does not contain refresh_token

are you getting an access token back that you can use? is the code being applied to the body.

It seems that you're supposed to provide the oauth2.AccessTypeOffline and oauth2.ApprovalForce args in AuthCodeURL() when initiating the OAuth process, not when requesting for the access token 
url := googleproject.OauthConfig.AuthCodeURL(oauthState, oauth2.ApprovalForce, oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)

@LindaLawton-DaImTo Thanks for the example
